# Processing records speed

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I realise this is a non-specific code question. But I suspect that people with answers are on this forum.

I am receiving a large amount of records of < 100 bytes via TCP at a rate of 10 per millisecond.

I have to parse and process the data and that takes me 100 microseconds - so I am pretty maxed out.

Does 100 microseconds seem large?

Here is an example of the kind of processing I do with LINQ. It is really convenient - but is it inherently slow?

```
    public void Process()
    {
        try
        {
            int ptr = PayloadOffset + 1;
            var cPair = MessageData.GetString(ref ptr, 7);
            var orderID = MessageData.GetString(ref ptr, 15);

            if (Book.CPairs.ContainsKey(cPair))
            {
                var cPairGroup = Book.CPairs[cPair];
                if (cPairGroup.BPrices != null)
                {                    
                    cPairGroup.BPrices.ForEach(x => { x.BOrders.RemoveAll(y => y.OrderID.Equals(orderID)); });
                    cPairGroup.BPrices.RemoveAll(x => x.BOrders.Count == 0);
                }
            }
         }
    }

    public class BOrderGroup
    {
        public double Amount;
        public string OrderID;
    }

    public class BPriceGroup
    {
        public double BPrice;
        public List<BOrderGroup> BOrders;
    }
    public class CPairGroup
    {
        public List<BPriceGroup> BPrices;
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, CPairGroup> CPairs;
```

Comment: No, LINQ is not "inherently slow".

Comment: How have you determined that it takes 100 microseconds to process the data? How are you getting sub millisecond time resolution?

Comment: Also show us the definition of your classes

Comment: I am using a StopWatch and checking elapsed time.

Comment: You're not actually using Linq. I can see Dictionary<T> and List<T> methods.

Comment: @Milney I added some class definitions

Comment: Profile the code, fix the hot spots, repeat.

Comment: Is this a streamed single connection or a new connection per each request?  Is this raw TCP socket or something like an HTTP request?  Are you sure the code is slow here?  Are you processing these requests Sync or Async?  Are you IO bound or CPU bound?

Comment: How many items are in your list and dictionary? You can consider using a HashSet instead of a List if there are a large number of items and you have an easy way to hash them... You could also consider keeping some kind of weighted-heap or tree structure based on count so that it is very quick to find the ones with empty structures

Comment: BPrices has max 100 items, BPrices max 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other have mentioned, LINQ is not inherently slow. But it can be slower than equivalent non-LINQ code (this is why Roslyn team has "Avoid LINQ" guide under [coding conventions](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Contributing-Code)).

If this is your hot path and you need every microsecond than you should probably implement logic in such a way:

```
public void Process()
{
    try
    {
        int ptr = PayloadOffset + 1;
        var cPair = MessageData.GetString(ref ptr, 7);
        var orderID = MessageData.GetString(ref ptr, 15);

        if (Book.CPairs.TryGetValue(cPair, out CPairGroup cPairGroup) && cPairGroup != null)
        {
            for (int i = cPairGroup.BPrices.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var x = cPairGroup.BPrices[i];
                for (int j = x.BOrders.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    var y = x.BOrders[j];
                    if (y.OrderID.Equals(orderID))
                    {
                        x.BOrders.RemoveAt(j);
                    }
                }
                if (x.BOrders.Count == 0)
                {
                    cPairGroup.BPrices.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main points:

- Avoid double dictionary lookup by using `TryGetValue`
- Single iteration over `cPairGroup.BPrices`
- In place modification of structures by iterating backwards
- This code should not contain any additional heap allocations

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to create a solution for me so specifically. I will implement and test this tomorrow and report what the outcome is. Once again, thank you.

Comment: Good implementation. This is as fast as you can go with C# and reasonable readability.